# Assigning client certificates to users

Tags: .net, ssl, client, certificate

We are trying to authenticate users from a particular group with client certificates installed on their machines in addition to user credentials. 
I followed the steps in this article - http://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates/.

I still cannot see the client certificate being requested by the server or the client certificate being passed to the server even though the CA used to generate the client certificates is in Trusted Root certificate store on clients and server. The IIS on the server is configured to accept client certificates since not all users will have the certificates installed.

Do I need to do anything specific in .NET code on the server side to explicitly request the client certificate?

Comment: You have to configure the server to ask for a client certificate, but I can't advise you how to do that in .NET.